# cortex-m3 can't debug. reason - SIGINT

Tags: gdb, cortex-m

I try to debug cortex-M3 microcontroller. There is SysTick interrupt enabled in firmware. So I can't debug program. There is what i get:

```
 C:\Users\al\Desktop\eclipse\arm-toolchain\bin>arm-none-eabi-gdb.exe ../../work_d
    ir/mdr1986be91_94_dev_board/Debug/mdr1986be91_94_dev_board.elf
    GNU gdb (Sourcery G++ Lite 2011.03-42) 7.2.50.20100908-cvs
    ...
    (gdb) target remote localhost:3333
    ...
    (gdb) c
    Continuing.

    Program received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
    0x0000001c in ?? ()
        at ../Libraries/MDR32F9Qx_StdPeriph_Driver/src/MDR32F9Qx_rst_clk.c:1642
    1642        statusreg = MDR_BKP->REG_0F;
    (gdb)
```

Debugging is stopped when an interrupt occurs. How to fix that?

Comment: What is in the OpenOCD config and in `.gdbinit`?

Comment: GDBinit file is empty. Config file is:                                                                  source [find interface/ftdi/olimex-arm-usb-ocd-h.cfg]
source [find target/mdr32f9q2i.cfg]

Answer (score 0):

You can tell debugger not to stop on some signal with handle command. So in your case it would be:

handle SIGINT nostop

More about it [in gdb manual](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Signals.html).

Comment: Thank you for answer. If i set nostop command i get in the loop:   
    Program received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
    mdr32f9q2i.cpu -- clearing lockup after double fault

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Seems there's something I'm missing with respect to using the Particle Photon debug shield, and OpenOCD/GNU debugger.